# HTML background will not play

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to activate a video background. However, I can't get it to play.

```
  <section class="home-section home-full-height bg-dark-30" id="home" data-background="assets/images/section-5.jpg">
        <div class="video-player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://youtu.be/x4JSQ7hQCec', containment:'.home-section', startAt:18, mute:false, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:false, showYTLogo:false, vol:25}></div>
        <div class="video-controls-box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="video-controls"><a class="fa fa-volume-up" id="video-volume" href="#">&nbsp;</a><a class="fa fa-pause" id="video-play" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I have attempted to modify /  remove:

```
<section class="home-section home-full-height bg-dark-30" id="home" data-background="assets/images/section-5.jpg">
```

It does nothing.

Comment: You're missing an end quote on the `data-property` attribute. I have no idea if that's the problem (there's not much to go on here - AFAIK, Bootstrap doesn't have a native video player component).

Comment: Your `<div class="video-player">` has a malformed `data-property` attribute that's missing its closing quote.

Comment: @Dai Thanks (quote was missing), now I'm just getting video unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You can display video with iframe as below

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://youtu.be/x4JSQ7hQCec?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Or use video tag as below

```
<video class="video-fluid z-depth-1" autoplay loop controls muted>
<source src="https://youtu.be/x4JSQ7hQCec" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```